# how do I make my Korean name from my Chinese name?

Tags: translation, names

I want to make my Korean name from my Chinese name but I can't seem to find it anywhere. my Chinese name is 施芸榛.

Answer (score 1):

Google Translates says it's 시윤전. 윤전 is not how it appears in Korean Hanja Dictionary. In all likelihood, your name would be pronounced as 시운진.

施 베풀 시, 옮길 이 (https://hanja.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=%E6%96%BD)

芸 평지 운, 재주 예/심을 예 (https://hanja.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=%E8%8A%B8)

榛 개암나무 진 (https://hanja.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=%E6%A6%9B)

Depending on which meaning you take from 芸, it could also be 시예진.

Comment: 운진 sounds like a man and 예진 sounds like a woman, so it might be a good idea to choose between them depending on OP's gender rather than by meaning.